# What is the best way to handle Json api request in symfony 2.7/2.8

Tags: json, symfony, request

what is the best way to handle Json api request in symfony?
for example I have api of customers that allowed me to add new customer, edit and delete, and read as well

my question is how to develope it in symfony, as a bundle? like i have a database? with entity class? 
if you have any tutorial it will be great

Answer (score 1):

**As a Client:**

You can use Guzzle to make HTTP calls for you and then convert the json responses using native json_decode.
Other option is to use a Rest client, you will find many of them on packagist, here is one:
https://packagist.org/packages/Mashape/unirest-php

**As a Server:**

FOSRestBundle, its gonna provide you with many features that you'll need. here is a tutorial:
http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/

Of course you should check for more sources as well, I have a project of my own which uses it and you can check some code:
https://github.com/renatomefidf/sammui

You can also check the LiipHelloBundle for other multiple usages and examples:
https://github.com/liip/LiipHelloBundle

***Good luck!***

Comment: thx but if you have an example for json parsing from remote Api?.. and not create new api 
thx

Comment: Sorry, I took your question wrong, you want to consume an API? You can use Guzzle for that and make the Api calls. Another option is to use a rest client, like this: http://unirest.io/php.html

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check if it suits for you!